# How can I interpolate and smooth 3D point clouds in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, interpolation, spline, point-clouds

I am hoping to get some help with a point cloud data processing problem I am faced with. Basically, I have lots of point cloud data that is patchy and noisey. My aim is therefore to approximate data where it is missing in the “patchy areas” and apply some form of light smoothing to filter the noise.

My first attempt to solve this was the interpolation methods in MATLAB. This was executed as follows and provided good results, in that the interpolated Z points across the working XY grid looks like the shape I am expecting.

```
% Load Point Cloud:
Point_Cloud  = importdata(‘Point_Cloud_1.txt')
x            = Point_Cloud(1,:)';
y            = Point_Cloud(2,:)';
z            = Point_Cloud(3,:)';

% Interpolate inspection points:
Density = 300;
[X,Y]   = meshgrid(linspace(min(x), max(x), Density), linspace(min(y), max(y), Density));
F       = scatteredInterpolant(x, y, z, 'natural','linear');
Z       = F(X,Y);
Int_PC  = [reshape(X,Density^2,1) reshape(Y,Density^2,1) reshape(Z,Density^2,1)];
Int_PC(any(isnan(Int_PC{i}),2),:) = [];  

% Plot results:
scatter3(x, y, z, 20, 'r', 'fill'); % Original data
hold on;
scatter3(Int_PC(:,1), Int_PC(:,2), Int_PC(:,3), 20, 'r', 'fill'); % Interpolated data
```

The problem with this is that noisey data is used to compute the interpolant, F, so the above code only solves the patchy data problem.

I then considered spline fitting using the Curve Fitting Toolbox. The thin-plate smoothing spline seems to make sense as it accepts scattered (non-gridded) data and it does not interpolate all points, thereby smoothing noise. The code for this is below. When executed, the results are disappointing because the fit between the original points and the computed surface is very poor (beyond what is needed to smooth noise).

```
Spline = tpaps([x;y],z);
fnplt(Spline)
```

[Thin plate spline example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxRd1.jpg)

Could anybody suggest any solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: did you try to use different values for the extra argument `p` for `tpaps`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply shamalaia. I have not yet experimented with p mainly because I do not understand how to select it. Do you have any info on this or a reasonable range to try?

Comment: can't you simply delete the noise (with a threshold for example, or a moving window) and run your script after this operation ?

Comment: This could certainly be a good option. I can see how a threshold would work when there is noise only in one of x, y or z but I am unsure how to do this when there is noise in each one. Also, the data is scattered rather than arranged in a uniform grid. Could you recommend a method? Also, do you know of a window based method that is suitable for scattered 3D data with noise in each dimension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One proposition, using the Savitzky-Golay Filter:

So

1. Use this filter
2. Use your code to complete the missing part.

**EXAMPLE**

```
%We build the noisy 3D point cloud

[X,Y] = meshgrid(0:0.1:4.9,0:0.1:4.9);
Z = sin(X)+cos(Y)+0.5*rand(50,50);

% The smoothing (with sgolayfilt(Z,order,length of the moving windows))
t1 = sgolayfilt(Z.',2,25); %smoothing over the x-axis
t2 = sgolayfilt(Z,2,25); %smoothing over the y-axis
t  = (t1.'+t2)/2; %smoothing in booth directions

surf(X,Y,t)
```

**Before smoothing**

[image: before]

**After smoothing**

[image: after]

**EDIT**

The same operation but with scattered data:

```
%random X and Y

X = rand(100,1)*5;
Y = rand(100,1)*5;

Z = sin(X)+cos(Y);

%Calculate the interpolant
F =  scatteredInterpolant(X,Y,Z);

%Fix the grid size
gs = 0.1; %grid size

tx = min(X(:)):gs:max(X(:));
tz = min(Y(:)):gs:max(Y(:));

%Scattered X,Y to gridded x,y
[x,y] = meshgrid(tx,ty);

%Interpolation over z-axis
z = F(x,y);

t1 = sgolayfilt(z.',2,5);
t2 = sgolayfilt(z,2,5);

t  = (t1.'+t2)/2;

surf(X,Y,t)
colormap winter
```

Comment: That looks excellent! Thank you very much :) Do you know of a variation that is suitable for scattered data rather than gridded?

Comment: Ho scattered, ... I miss this information ! Ok i will try to edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks obchardon! Much appreciated!

Comment: but one question:  you already have gridded your scattered data in your code no ?

Comment: Ok I edited my answer, I haven't tried yet but it should work.

Comment: This looks very useful. So it seems that the correct way is to interpolate and then smooth? I'll give this a try :)

Comment: That's only one solution ! There is not A correct way.